# How to convert a HashMap to a K/V-String in Java 8 with Streams

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I want to create a string of the key value pairs of my `HashMap<String, String> m` as fast as possible.

I tried:

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
buf.append("[");
for (String key : m.keySet()) {
   buf.append(key);
   buf.append("=");
   buf.append(m.get(key));
   buf.append(";");
}
buf.append("]");
```

With Java8 I tried:

```
m.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.joining("; " , "[" , "]"));
```

Is there any faster, better code to do that?
It seems to be costly to append the keys and Values in the map function, doesn't it?

Comment: When you profiled both of these approaches, which ran faster than the other? And how much faster?

Comment: I would not worry about performance in this case **unless** it's a critical part of the system and it's pointed out as a bottleneck by usage of a profiler or a similar tool. If you haven't done this before and you *think* this code is not optimal, then I̶ ̶k̶n̶o̶w̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶  maybe you're wrong and should test it first.

Comment: FWIW - The result of `m.toString()` may be close enough for you for this not to matter.

Comment: Have you tried using a parallelStream?

Comment: @AnonymousCoward parallelStream is overhyped, I would be careful with recommending it not knowing the actual aplication it is used in (especially in webserver)

Comment: Please note that in JDK 9 `StringJoiner` (which is the underlying class for `Collectors.joining`) was optimized, thus stream implementation will work about 20-25% faster than in JDK 8 (though still not as fast as naive).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
map -> map.entrySet().stream().map(Entry::toString).collect(joining(";", "[", "]"))
```

(Note that I omitted the imports.)

Like [Luiggi Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303273/how-to-convert-a-hashmap-to-a-k-v-string-in-java-8-with-streams#comment50596980_31303273) said:

> I would not worry about performance in this case unless it's a critical part of the system and it's pointed out as a bottleneck by usage of a profiler or a similar tool. If you haven't done this before and you think this code is not optimal, then I̶ ̶k̶n̶o̶w̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ maybe you're wrong and should test it first.

Comment: OP's 'Collectors.joining()' call had the delimiter, prefix, suffix misordered. Your solution fixed that.

Comment: Note that while `Entry.toString()` usually returns `key = value`, it's not explicitly required by the [Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) interface, thus you may hit the map implementation which returns something else. I'd prefer explicit concatenation like in the question.

Comment: I have looked at `Entry` interface. I could not fine any declaration `toString`. Could you give explain how `Entry::toString()` define ? Another thing, only `Entry::toString` can not resolve in my end. I need to do `Map.Entry::toString()`.

Comment: @seal `toString()` is declared by `java.lang.Object`, so it's inherited by everything. If you do `import java.util.Map.Entry;`, then you can use `Entry::toString` directly.

Comment: @gdejohn It is hard to understand how come interface find `toString` method ? there is no super interface or no interface inherited from Object class then how interface can use that `toString` method ?

Comment: @seal http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder instead of buffer.

Javadoc => Class StringBuffer

"The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization." [Class StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)

Comment: is it faster than the solution with the stream? Could both be combined?

Comment: While using StringBuilder may be faster than StringBuffer for the first piece of code, the question is specifically about the speed of the second piece of code, as @LuiggiMendoza points out.

Comment: And for readers, the compiler create a `StringBuilder` in second case for this piece of code: `entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue())` on every iteration, so there's no need to use another `StringBuilder`. And `Collectors#joining` will use a `StringJoiner` that uses a `StringBuilder` behind the scenes for you, I guess there's no real improvement using a `StringBuilder` at all.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, btw in JDK 9 it doesn't use the `StringBuilder` anymore.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Test
public void testMapPrint() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("a", "b");
    map.put("c", "d");

    map.entrySet().stream()
            .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue()));
}
```

Comment: Printing each pair to console separately takes a lot of time. Collecting everything in a String{Builder,Builder} and then printing it is most probably faster.

Comment: Well, if you want to go into microbenchmarking you should also consider situation where char array in string builder is extending (its also costly, by default char[16] is created) :)

Comment: If you want to print a map directly, there is no need for a `Stream`. Just use `map.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k+":"+v));`